# Error with getStaticProps in Next.js 13.4 in the 'app' folder

Tags: html, css, reactjs, typescript, next.js

[this is the error i am getting over here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gIy1G.png).
I'm working on a Next.js 13.4 project, and I'm encountering an issue when trying to use `getStaticProps` in the 'app' folder. My goal is to fetch data during server-side rendering for all pages. However, I'm getting the following error: